# Is it possible to make curved shape in 3d perspective div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*There is a video of concept desktop.* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ftpcHD3378

Well, may there is a way to make curved shape div... or at least to fake it. All I want to do is to bend div as it looks like a bit curved in 3D. I don't need any features as in video. If there is a way to do this in javascript/jquery tell me plz.

[image]

Comment: I think your best hope would be using CSS Filters, that allows you to use SVG filters to do the trick. Otherwise, a Custom Filter (check [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/03/Introduction-to-Custom-Filters-aka-CSS-Shaders)). I don't think Javascript would be of any help here, unless you're talking about a static image.

Comment: You need to use CSS3 _transform_ property, check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for a starter.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is to use the perspective CSS property, I created a web photo gallery wall using this method, with similar results that you are looking for.

I used this website to help me build my gallery:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: I know this method, something like this: http://www.digicrafts.com.hk/components/assets/product/lrproduct/LRTile3D/description10.jpg . It only works for separate elements. Every single element is rotated at right angle in 3d perspective and it creates fake curved effect. This is not the same for one element to curve. We need to wrap div around the curve to create a curved shape, but maybe there is easier way?